# Assign unique ID to mixed list of strings and substrings

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries of strings (eg people names) which are either complete or just fragments:

```
names = [
    {"text": "Alice"},
    {"text": "Bob"},
    {"text": "Bob Ross"},
    {"text": "Twain"},
    {"text": "Ross"},
    {"text": "Alice Twain"},
    {"text": "Alice"},
    {"text": "Charles"},
]
```

and would like to add an id to each dictionary unique to each string, irrespective of whether full or fragment.

I have written a small function to sort the list of strings in descending length order:

```
def sortlen(lst):
    lst.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
    return lst
```

therefore:

```
print(sortlen([name["text"] for name in names]))
```

would yield:

```
['Alice Twain', 'Bob Ross', 'Charles', 'Alice', 'Twain', 'Alice', 'Ross', 'Bob']
```

What I would like to end up with, given the above example, is the following:

```
names = [
    {"text": "Alice", "id": 2},
    {"text": "Bob", "id": 1},
    {"text": "Bob Ross", "id": 1},
    {"text": "Twain", "id": 2},
    {"text": "Ross", "id": 1},
    {"text": "Alice Twain", "id": 2},
    {"text": "Alice", "id": 2},
    {"text": "Charles", "id": 3},
]
```

Not sure which algorithm/code to apply to the descending length list of strings.

Comment: What happens if the names are Alex Smith, Bob Smith, and Smith?

Comment: The possibility is there but remote enough for me to ignore. The sources are very short texts mentioning people. In your example they would only use the full form to avoid misunderstandings. Good point though :)